# input loses focus inside an Iframe in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a table in which the user can tab through cells. This is done by inserting an input tag into the cell (This also allows the user to edit information). When the user hits tab, the previous cell's input tag is removed, and an input tag for the next cell is inserted and focused.

This works fine in all cases except in an iframe in IE9 and 10. For some reason the next cell is focused for a second and then loses focus. When the input tag is blured, the input tag is removed from the cell, so essentially it seems like tab doesn't work and the user can't edit the next cell's content. It looks like the body tag of the iframe gains focus when this happens. I can't blur the body tag as that causes windows to switch in IE.

I've created a very simple jsFiddle that shows this behavior - https://jsfiddle.net/Lpo2s61m/10/

`<input type="text" class = "test1" value='test1'/>`

```
$('.test1').bind({
keydown: function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 9) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
},
keyup: function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 9) {
        $('<input type="text" class = "test2"/>').insertAfter($('.test1'));
        $('.test2').val('test2');
        bindEvents();
        $('.test1').remove();
        $('.test2').focus();
   }
}
});
```

Because jsFiddle loads the html in an iframe, it is reproducible just running this in IE.

It's similar to this question - [Setting Focus to an iFrame in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045707/setting-focus-to-an-iframe-in-ie) - where they say it shows the cursor for a second and then it disappears. However, none of those solutions worked for me. For reference I'm using jQuery 1.8.3.

The only work around I have so far is to delay binding the blur event on my input so it doesn't disappear. I'm looking for a better solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.